# Android: setting up utf-8 encoding to String and Array

Tags: java, android, string, encoding, utf-8

I'm lithuanian and I'm creating app in lithuanian language, but Strings can't contain letters such as: `ą, č, ę, ė, į, š, ų, ū, ž...`

I searched over the internet for simple way to make it possible, but I ended up there...

There is some of my code that I want to modify:

```
if (dayOfWeek.equals("Wednesday")) {
    dayOfWeek = "Treciadienis"; //this should be Trečiadienis
}
```

And I have Array that has bunch of these letters. How should I deal with it?

```
static JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(data);
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: you could use i18n, place all string you need in xml. Are they predefined or you getting text from web also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A string can contain the letter ą. The following code `dayOfWeek = "Treciadienis";`.

1. Do you have checked if your file is encoded in UTF-8 ? For that under Eclipse, do File => Properties, and you'll see in the bottom the Text file encoding.
2. If you really can not, I think your talking about a a with ogonek, the other solution is to refer on bytes value of the String, and to do : `dayOfWeek = "Tre".concat(new String(new byte[]{(byte) 0xC4})).concat("iadienis");` (yep, quite extreme, but it works).

Comment: It worked with the first one! Thank you! I was scared when I Read second one.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common if your're using Windows that Eclipse sets the default encoding to Cp1252, which you must change to UTF-8 so you're able to use that kind of characters hardcoded in your .java files.
Don't forget that you can also use the string constructor:

```
String(byte[] data, String charsetName)
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding Tod gahfy's answer:

Instead of adding individual bytes you can use the `\uxxxx` syntax within the String. Xxxx is the Unicode code point of the character. This is of course more annoying than using UTF-8 encoding but less annoying than adding bytes.